# Deduce all possible configuration for a given CONF param FANUC

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, inverse-kinematics, design, algorithm

I am working on the "CONF" parameter of FANUC Robots.

The "CONF" param determine the pose of the robot (maybe to have only one inverse kinematics solution). This configuration is based on 3 mains parameters : the position of the wrist (Flip/No-flip), the elbow (Up/Down)  and waist (Top/Bottom).

I want to find a way to develop a function which the purpose is to give in enter a CONF param (like NUT of FUT) and return all the possible angles configurations of the robots which satisfied this CONF param (n,6 array).

I have managed to find the min and max angles for J5 to satisfied the flip or no-flip CONF parameter (which is dependent of +/-180° on J4 and J6).

If we take a 6 DOF robot (J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6), it's quite simple to find all the possible configuration with a fixed J2 and fixed J3.

But when I want to include J2 and J3, the problem become way more complex.

Have you any clue ?

Thanks in advance for your help, have a good day!

Comment: Could you please better explain what the function should do? give you the joint ranges which satisfy the CONF parameter? What environment are you working in? should this function run on the robot or on a PC? Matlab, python, c/c++?

Comment: @50k4 Yes : giving the configuration space of the robot, i would like to be able to reduce it to sort only the configurations satisfying the CONF parameters. 
I am working under Webots with Python